# Is "would you be keen to consider___?" too cheesy to use?

Tags: expressions, british-english, politeness, appropriate

On a formal / professional email, is the following question acceptable, or is it too much politeness it looks unprofessional?

The intention is to ask someone, who is not a subordinate, to do something. To be used in England.

```
Would you be keen to consider _________?
```

Comment: It's not "politeness" it's the word *keen* that seems too informal and/or dated so as to be out of place here.

Comment: Use of keen peaked in 1920, but it's been staging a comback since 2000:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keen&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeen%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @WayfaringStranger- take a look through the first two pages of hits (1980-2008) and I couldn't find a single one that matched our expected usage.  It's mostly used a last name, or a city name, or a record label from 1957.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger- But this one is interesting https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+keen+to%3Aeng_gb_2012%2CI+am+keen+to%3Aeng_us_2012%2CI+am+eager+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20keen%20to%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20keen%20to%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20eager%20to%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, don't say that.

I'd might say, "Perhaps you'd consider ____?"

Comment: Or "Would you be willing to consider ..."